# Converting database of coordinates to physical addresses

Tags: database, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

I'm trying to make a real estate agency website and got an idea of saving addresses as coordinates to database (because text addresses can be difficult)

So I have two main questions:

1) **Is it possible to search objects by street** if their addresses are saved as coordinates? And how difficult is it? Maybe you could give a working example in any web-programming language or advise a good walkthrough.

2) **Is it a feasible approach?** Maybe it has awful drawbacks I don't see.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is in fact possible to convert the latitude and longitude of a location into an address. This is achieved through the Google Maps Reverse Geocoding service through the Javascript API.

[Take a look at this site to read up a bit more on reverse geocoding and how you could make it work for your project.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ReverseGeocoding)

**Here is a code sample of a reverse geocoding request:**
[Live example here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-reverse)

```
 function geocodeLatLng(geocoder, map, infowindow) {
    var input = document.getElementById('latlng').value;
    var latlngStr = input.split(',', 2);
    var latlng = {lat: parseFloat(latlngStr[0]), lng: parseFloat(latlngStr[1])};
    geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
      if (status === 'OK') {
        if (results[0]) {
          map.setZoom(11);
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map
          });
          infowindow.setContent(results[0].formatted_address);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        } else {
          window.alert('No results found');
        }
      } else {
        window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
      }
    });
  }
```